# Use dynamic list in whiptail

Tags: bash, text, dialog, whiptail

I need to build a dynamic list with checkboxes in whiptail.
But using a variable\dynamic bash output doesn't help me.

I tryed used this command

```
whiptail --title "Operations" --checklist "Select Operation" 22 80 14 $array
```

Output of variable `array` is

```
"cash3" "54311 May 25 10:10 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash10" "10475 May 28 18:23 22A763D0-8203-11E9-82FE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash14" "9905 May 27 15:55 22A763D0-8203-11E9-86FD-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash13" "11780 May 29 09:32 22A763D0-8203-11E9-66AD-0007321A6EB4" OFF
```

what fully corresponds to the whiptail syntax of the command, but this command is not executed.

When using the same data, but not through a variable whiptail works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use the first element with `$array`. You can make use of the entire array with `${array[@]}`.

This will work:

```
#! /bin/bash

array=("cash3" "54311 May 25 10:10 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash10" "10475 May 28 18:23 22A763D0-8203-11E9-82FE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash14" "9905 May 27 15:55 22A763D0-8203-11E9-86FD-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash13" "11780 May 29 09:32 22A763D0-8203-11E9-66AD-0007321A6EB4" OFF)

whiptail --title "Operations" --checklist "Select Operation" 22 80 14 "${array[@]}"
```

Note that without quoting the array (`"`), whiptail will not work correctly.

Comment: whiptail return me only help page on this command\.
Probably $array not correct, but I don't know what format need for this.
now its looks like
```
$ echo $array                                                                        
"cash3" "54311 May 25 10:10 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash15" "10475 May 29 14:18 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash14" "10475 May 29 14:18 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF "cash13" "10475 May 29 14:18 22A763D0-8203-11E9-39BE-0007321A6EB4" OFF
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'd used the the array example from the question.

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't get it working as a single string, so I think you're bound to use arrays. ps. would you please accept my answer? :-)